# ASP.net WebAPI or WCF

Tags: asp.net-web-api

Our client side is .NET web applications, windows desktop application, or
iOS App.  We have several small web MVC applications using web API now. We will have a lot more new applications and some will be big and complex. So

1. Does web API support transferring binary data?
2. how does web API support reliable message transfer when network is not 
   good?
3. how does web API support message security?
4. Can I move web API project out from those web applications and put them 
   into a separate centralized library location like what WCF can do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Does web API support transferring binary data?
```

You can easily add any serialization protocol, e.g. Protocol Buffers.

```
how does web API support reliable message transfer when network is not good?
```

You can rely on TCP/IP. In case you have some troubles on your transport layer, you can always implement double checking, "retry"-strategy, etc. actually it's all up to you.

```
how does web API support message security?
```

HTTPS built-in. A lot of levels to inject custom authentication and authorization layer. In ASP5 additional tools were added for auth.

```
Can I move web API project out from those web applications and put them into a separate centralized library location like what WCF can do?
```

Not so clear. You can easily create a microservice architecture with WebAPI. You can separate any submodules into different services. And even make them self-hosted. It's very flexible and easy-to-cook.